# Xamarin - System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: android, xamarin, input

My goal is to create an Android-App with VS2019 (Xamarin). This app has 2 input fields (Type "numberDecimal"). The user can enter 2 numbers, which the app shall divide without pressing buttons or else. The result should be shown in a TextView.

Example: First number = 2,54   |||  Second number = 13,44 |||  Result = 5,29

So far I have created "EW" for the first number and "EV" for the second number. I thought that both need to be converted into double-format ("EW2", "EV2"), so "result" can divide them.

But I always get a Error-Message "System.FormatException:** 'Input string was not in a correct format."
Maybe I did something completely wrong or maybe it is a simple one. But after days of searching and trying different ways, I am in a dead end ...

````
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;

namespace App2
{
    [Activity(Label = "VD-Rechner", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
       TextView VD_Ergebnis;
        EditText EW;
        EditText EV;
        double EW2;
        double EV2;
        double result;
       

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            VD_Ergebnis = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Ergebnis);

            EW = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Einwaage);
            EV = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Endvolumen);

            EW2 = double.Parse(EW.Text);   //ERROR-MESSAGE HERE
            EV2 = double.Parse(EV.Text);

            result = EV2 / EW2;

            VD_Ergebnis.Text = result.ToString();
        }
    }
}






<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="59.0dp"
        android:text="Verdünnungsfaktor"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/Ergebnis"
        android:textColor="#ff00c853"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/Einwaage"
        android:textColor="#ffffd600"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Einwaage"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/EinwaageText"
        android:textColor="#ffffd600"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <EditText
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/Endvolumen"
        android:textColor="#ff2979ff"
        android:typeface="serif" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Endvolumen"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/EndvolumenText"
        android:textColor="#ff2979ff"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</LinearLayout>

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I always get a Error-Message "System.FormatException:** 'Input string was not in a correct format

This is because the editText's text is empty at the begining. And to update the textView at runtime, try to specify the value in the TextChanged event of `EditText`.

Check the code:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    ...
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        VD_Ergebnis = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Ergebnis);
        EW = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Einwaage);
        EV = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Endvolumen);

        EW.TextChanged += delegate
        {
            if (EW.Text != "")
            {
                EW2 = double.Parse(EW.Text);

                if (EV.Text != "")
                {
                    result = EV2 / EW2;
                    VD_Ergebnis.Text = result.ToString();
                }
            }
        };
        EV.TextChanged += delegate
        {
            if (EV.Text != "")
            {
                EV2 = double.Parse(EV.Text);

                if (EW.Text != "")
                {
                    result = EV2 / EW2;
                    VD_Ergebnis.Text = result.ToString();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Work gif:

[image]